# To half the size of image on hover for what I have so far do I use a var

Tags: jquery

This is a 24 hr trial site of what I'm doing 
http://trialsites.ihoststudio.com/trialsite361583/website/

If you view generated source you'll see I'm working inside a program that I am 

 removing attributes then adding my own, then adding a class

 Then I'm using hover to preview the image before I go to fancybox on the click

 (which is why I did the live trial - easier to show you)

My question is how do I make that hover image half size but I keep getting errors 

I'm assuming it's a var but I'm new at jQuery and lucky I've got this far

 
is it var img / 2  then apply that or do you use .css('img', e. / 2) just before .appendTo
I don't seem to get it to work?

--------------------added code------------

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var offsetX = 20;
    var offsetY = 10;

$('[id^=TMBOBJ]').each(function() {
var $a = $(this).find('a');
$a.attr('href' , $a.attr('href').replace('html', 'jpg'));
$a.removeAttr('onclick');
$a.removeAttr('target');
$a.addClass("nextfancy");
$a.attr('rel', 'group')
});

$('a.nextfancy').hover(function(e) {
var href = $(this).attr('href');
$('<img id="largeImage" src="' + href + '" alt="big image" />')
.css('top', e.pageY + offsetY)
.css('left', e.pageX + offsetX)
.appendTo('body');
}, function() {
$('#largeImage').remove();
});

$('a.nextfancy').mousemove(function(e) {
$("#largeImage").css('top', e.pageY + offsetY).css('left', e.pageX + offsetX);
});

$("a.nextfancy").fancybox({
'transitionIn': 'elastic',
'transitionOut': 'elastic',
'overlayColor': '#000000',
'titlePosition': 'inside'
});
});
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that is causing the problem?

Comment: There I added the code as well